# How to use an SWC file on Flash CS4

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, swc, cs4

I am trying to understand how to use an swc file I have in Flash CS4.

As I search this subject on the web regarding flesh there are 2 issues:
1. That I know how to deal with Flex and the explanations are referring flex.
2. I haven't found 1 simple example that demonstrates where to put the swc file, what to write on the fla in order to make it work, etc...

I want to ask if someone knows of a simple exampe - or - step-by-step example so that I would know how it works...

Alon

Comment: What SWC are you trying to use?  Was it created using the Flex Framework?  Does it have Flex Framework dependencies?  If so, it'll be difficult to use it in Flash Pro; as you'll have to manually set up / load / configure the Flex Framework.

Answer (score 3):

You can put the swc file wherever you want. Quite often it is put in a 'libs' folder at the same level as the 'src' folder.

You then need to link the swc to your fla. You do this by File>Publish Settings>Flash>Settings>Library Path>Browse to SWC File (the little red envelope)

You will now be able to reference assets and code within the swc. If you created the swc or there is an API, it will be much easier for you, especially if you are working within the Flash IDE.

Answer (score 1):

you can change the .swc extention to .zip and then extract the contents.  That way you can at least get at some or most of the code if you wanted to convert its capabilities into a class or external AS.

Comment: thanks for the tip, the problem was it contained only .swf but I managed to figure that out